# Redirect based on port number?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to redirect `domain.com:88 to domain.com:8080` using htaccess & mod_rewrite?
And example please?

If htaccess can't do it, waht are other options?

Answer (score 1):

If you get requests on different ports you need to have servers listening on those ports. Inside those servers you can certainly configure rewriting rules, you don't even have to check the port, since it is implicitly given inside the servers logic.

Note that you can configure several virtual  servers inside an apache http server.

You can also configure a single server to listen on several ports. Check for documentation about the `Listen` configuration option inside the http server configuration. Then indeed you have to test for the port. You can do that inside the rewriting module by using the `RewriteCond` command together with the `SERVER_PORT` variable. So something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ${SERVER_PORT} 88
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://some.server.addr:8080/$1 [QSA,L]
```